# SASS: import bourbon lib from another dir in stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, assets

I have a namespace let's say called "pro" and I want to put my sass assets inside `app/assets/stylesheets/pro/sellers`. I have nested controllers `cars` is inside `sellers`.

In my layout I have this `stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller]` so it's general. This generates the path `pro/sellers/cars.css.sass` for my config.

In the sass file I want to import the bourbon library, but I get this error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: ../functions/linear-gradient.
Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer(/my_project_path/app/assets/stylesheets/pro/sellers/cars.css.sass)
  (in /my_project_path/app/assets/stylesheets/pro/sellers/cars.css.sass)
```

Is it possible to do that import or is it a limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it's a known issue with nested imports in SASS.  There is a patch that might help posted here towards the bottom:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/26